Как исправить ошибку при установке pam_sqlite?
Для моего проекта необходимо установить pam_sqlite. Я клонировал репозиторий в директорию затем, запустил команду ./configure и получил ошибку
[zaha@fedora pam_sqlite]$ ./configure 
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking for pam_get_user in -lpam... no
checking for mhash_init in -lmhash... no
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh ./config.sub x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu failed

Никак не могу понять с чем она связана. Сижу на Fedora37.
